# Does $x_n \overset{w}{\rightarrow} x$ and $Tx_n \to y$ imply $y = Tx$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $T: X\to Y $be a bounded linear operator between reflexive Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$ , and let $\{x_n\}$ be sequence in $X$ with property $x_n \overset{w}{\rightarrow} x$ and $Tx_n \to y$. Can we conclude that $y=Tx$?

I'm even not sure this property holds in Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Continuous functions preserve limits.

Comment: @WilliamElliot  notice that the limit  taken on $x_n$ is not based on normed-topology. It is weak-topology.

Comment: Continuous functions preserve limits. in any topological space.

Comment: @WilliamElliot It seems you didn't get what I said.  Just to clarify issue consider this example:  the function $f(x) = sgn(x)$ is discontinuous wrt Euclidean topology, but it iscontinuous wrt to discrete topology.

Comment: Is T weakly continuous?

Comment: @WilliamElliot  That's almost what I asked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

True in any normed linear space. Any norm to norm bounded operator is also weak to weak continuous. Hence weak convergence of $(x_n)$  to $x$ implies weak convergence of $T(x_n)$ to $Tx$. Since $Tx_n \to y$ in the norm it also converges weakly. Since weak limit is unique we get $y=Tx$.

Comment: Thanks do have any reference for that  weak to weak continuous?

Comment: Let $x_n \to x$ weakly. Let $y^{*} \in Y^{*}$. Define $x^{*} $on $X$ by  $x^{*}(x)=y^{*}(Tx)$. You can easily verify that this is a continuous linear functional on $X$. Hence $x^{*}(x_n) \to x^{*}(x)$. This means $y^{*}(T(x_n)) \to y^{*}(Tx)$. Since this is true for all $y^{*} \in Y^{*}$ we see that $Tx_n \to TX$ weakly.